# jetty wildcard subdomain

Tags: dns, jetty, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I want to use wildcard subdomain on Jetty
*.mydomain.com
I have found that Jetty supports normal virtual hosts http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts
I have also seen such configuration in Apache using mod_proxy or mod_rewrite
Can I do this directly without Apache ?
If yes, will I need to setup a DNS server like bind9 to do wildcard subdomains ?
If no, how can I configure Apache with Jetty and will this affect Jetty's NIO performance ?